# Rails upload a picture using paperclip and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I using devise to manage my authentication, and want to add a new page where users can upload a picture , so when they sign in, they will be redirected to their profile where they can upload a picture, how do I go about that? Should I create a new controller for this matter or override devise's controllers and how will my route for this matter look like? help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a `User` model and `image` as its attachment field

You need add this to your `Application Controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
      upload_path
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) << :image
  end
end
```

You need to create an `upload` page and its corresponding `route`, where the user uploads the image.

Comment: And where do I add the upload action? in which controller?